# My user folder is inside a random folder

Tags: directory, home-directory, tree

Somehow I got the following file structure in `~/`

```
~
└── todo_app
    └── ~
```

I really don't know how this hapenned and how to solve it.

`cd ~` just goes to `~` and not `~/todo_app/~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was brave enought to `sudo rm -rf ~/todo_app/~` and it worked without deleting my home folder.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` to remove files and folders under your home directory.

Comment: The first `~` is not a real file/directory name, but just a Bash "shortcut" for your home directory. However the second `~` is just a file or directory. In your case, it seems that it was a "link file"  pointing to your home directory.

Comment: @Nmath, I know it, but it was saying that I didn't had permission to do that